# Travelling to Kyzyl, Tuva from Mörön, Mongolia

Tags: transportation, russia, mongolia, siberia, tuva

How would one get [from Mörön, Mongolia (near lake Khövsgöl), to Kyzyl, Tuva, Siberia, Russia](http://goo.gl/maps/zz37)?

Our prior research indicates that unless one holds a Russian or Mongolian passport, one will not be allowed to cross the border between these countries, except by air or the trans-Siberian railway.

However, neither of these options is viable, because the nearest airport to Kyzyl is Krasnoyarsk, from which it appears that the only way to [get to Kyzyl is via Abakan](http://goo.gl/maps/bgYe).

However, the journey between Abakan and Kyzyl is apparently an arduous one.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: When I lived in Mongolia, crossing the border by road was definitely possible for those not holding a Russian or Mongolian passport. But it was also only an option at very few border crossings, like the one north of Suhbaatar and the crossing all the way out west, where the Transmongolian enters the country. But, indeed, my information is some 8 years old.

Comment: I think my friend crossed from Russia into Mongolia last year. He was not allowed to go by bicycle, so they hitch-hiked and went with a car. That was possible on a French passport.

Comment: As per 2020, the nearest airport to Kyzyl is Kyzyl `KYZ`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crossing the border by road does seem to be an option, but only at [certain border crossing points](http://www.adventurebimbling.com/mongolia/mongolia_borders.html). (The crossing specified by Google Maps, unfortunately, seems to be sandwiched between the two ones open to foreign nationals.)  There are [some reports](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=725378) that you can either get permission or "talk your way across" if you're feeling up to the task (and possible rejection).  If you want to make totally sure, maybe contact an embassy in the area?

Mörön does have an airport, but there are only flights to Ulaanbator. There are no direct flights from there to Abakan, so you'd have to hop over to a major Russian city and then back to Abakan.  Basically, it would be in your interest to find a land route.

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems your only viable option is to use the Border near Koch Agach. Traveling to Tuva *is* gruesome, international bordercrossings between russia and mongolia are few and far in between. Also keep in mind that on the russian side there is a 50 km border control zone where you are not allowed to travel without permit - except you hold a valid visa and are on your way to or from a border crossing on a main route.